# Notations regarding Random Variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables

This is about notations used in the discussion of Random Variables in the book [*Schaum's Outline of Probability, Random Variables, and Random Processes*](https://www.dca.ufrn.br/~affonso/FTP/livros/Hsu_probabilidade.pdf) by Hwei Hsu, Chapter-2, Page-38.

> Let, we flip a coin thrice, and a random variable $X$ represents the number of heads.

Then,

a.   $S = \{TTT, HTT, THT, TTH, HHT, HTH, THH, HHH\}$.
 b.   $\zeta = TTT, HTT, THT, TTH, HHT, HTH, THH, HHH$.
 c.   $X(\zeta) = x = 0, 1, 2, 3$.
 d.   $X(\zeta_1) = X(\{TTT\}) = 0 = x_1$
 e.   $X(\zeta_2) = X(\{HTT\}) = 1 = x_2$
 f.   $X(\zeta_3) = X(\{THT\}) = 1 = x_2$
 g.   $X(\zeta_4) = X(\{TTH\}) = 1 = x_2$
 h.   $X(\zeta_5) = X(\{HHT\}) = 2 = x_3$
 i.   $X(\zeta_6) = X(\{HTH\}) = 2 = x_3$
 j.   $X(\zeta_7) = X(\{THH\}) = 2 = x_3$
 k.   $X(\zeta_8) = X(\{HHH\}) = 3 = x_4$
 l.   $(X=x) = \{TTT\}, \{HTT, THT, TTH\}, \{HHT, HTH, THH\}, \{HHH\}$.
 m.   $(X=0)=\{TTT\}$
 n.   $(X=1)=\{HTT, THT, TTH\}$
 o.   $(X=2)=\{HHT, HTH, THH\}$
 p.   $(X=3)=\{HHH\}$
 q.   $(X\le3) = \{TTT\}, \{HTT, THT, TTH\}, \{HHT, HTH, THH\}, \{HHH\}$.

.

**Is any of these assumptions incorrect?**

**Note.** kindly point out if there is any typo.

Comment: $X(\zeta)$ represents the number of heads in the event $\zeta$. Is that what your question is?

Answer (score 1):

The random variable $X$ is a function $S \to \mathbb{R}$.

Thus,  $X(\zeta)$ is the image of $\zeta$ induced by $X$.

That is, 
$$\begin{align}
X(\zeta)&=\{X(z): z \in \zeta\} \\
&= \{X(TTT), X(HTT), X(THT), X(TTH), X(HHT), X(HTH), X(THH), X(HHH)\} \\
&= \{0, 1, 2, 3\}\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Is this correct:  **c.**   $X(\zeta) = x = 0, 1, 2, 3$.  ?